# How to anchor a DIV to the bottom of a page?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a fixed-width DIV that I want to remain at the bottom of the browser's viewport.

Unfortunately, I haven't a clue where I would even begin to try to implement this.

Obviously the first thing to do is set `position` to `fixed`. But beyond that... no clue.

Comment: a good way to check on these sort of things is to install Firebug (on Firefox) and inspect a page that's using the effect you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 42):

See at css-tricks:

**[Fixed Footer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/)**

**CSS:**

```
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}

/* IE 6 */
* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution for people who favor a) modern browsers and 2) not including unnecessary library dependencies (cssstickyfooter.com)

Comment: The footer with expression is fixed at the bottom on load but scrolls with the page

Answer (score 23):

```
#mydiv{
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0px;
}
```

Comment: You should look through the link I posted instead.  There are fixes needed for IE and Opera.