# <tfoot> anchored to bottom of the page

Tags: html, footer

I am including code below as a footer for my webpage. However, using IE9 or Chrome, this footer is not anchored to the bottom of the page. How can I do that?

Thanks

```
<body>
[...]
 <tfoot valign="bottom">
    <tr><td>All rights reserved</td></tr>
  </tfoot>
</body>
```

**FIXED:** Using `<div>` instead of `<tfoot>`

Comment: ´tfoot´ belongs to a table element, not as a "footer". Use a ´div´ instead with position: fixed; bottom: 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must understand that TFOOT needs to be part of a TABLE element, as described here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/the-tfoot-element.html

Second, applying the "valign" attribute refers to the contents of the TFOOT element, not the TFOOT element itself.

The real answer to your question? Forget using a TFOOT element. I suggest looking at the following question and the resulting answer:

[How to anchor a DIV to the bottom of a page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971401/how-to-anchor-a-div-to-the-bottom-of-a-page)