# How to create responsive table with footer

Tags: html, css

I want to create a responsive table with footer. Right now i am using  tag But i am facing issue with the footer. It doesnot show properly on different screen sizes. Footer should be fixed to bottom of page. If user tries to resize the page it should show scroll in that case, with footer at bottom.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBumf.png)

```
<div class="container">
        <table class="tablelog">
            <thead  id="thead">
                <tr >
                    <th ><div  style="width:15px;"></div></th>
                    <th ><div  id="div-style">Column 1</div></th>
                    <th ><div  id="div-style">Column 2</div></th>
                    <th ><div  id="div-style">Column 3</div></th>
                    <th  id="last-column"><div >Column 4</div></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody  id="tbody">
                <tr  class="active">
                    <td  style="padding-right:15px;"><div  class="triangleright"></div></td>
                    <td ><div  id="div-style">value</div></td>
                    <td ><div  id="div-style">value</div></td>
                    <td >
                        <div  id="div-style">value</div>
                    </td>
                    <td  id="last-column">value</td>
                </tr><tr> 
                    <td  style="padding-right:15px;"><div></div></td>
                    <td ><div  id="div-style">value</div></td>
                    <td ><div  id="div-style">value</div></td>
                    <td >
                        <div  id="div-style">value</div>
                    </td>
                    <td  id="last-column">value</td>
                </tr><tr>
                    <td  style="padding-right:15px;"><div></div></td>
                    <td ><div  id="div-style">value</div></td>
                    <td ><div  id="div-style">value</div></td>
                    <td >
                        <div  id="div-style">value</div>
                    </td>
                    <td  id="last-column">value</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot >
                <div  id="page-selector-control">
                    <div  id="pageselectorButtonContainr">
                        <button  id="page-selector-button-control" type="button" disabled=""><img  id="page-selector-button-control-image" src="images/extreme-left.png"></button>
                        <button  id="page-selector-button-control" type="button" disabled=""><img  id="page-selector-button-control-image" src="images/arrow-left.png"></button>
                        <button  id="page-selector-button-control" type="button" disabled=""><img  id="page-selector-button-control-image" src="images/arrow-right.png"></button>
                        <button  id="page-selector-button-control" type="button" disabled=""><img  id="page-selector-button-control-image" src="images/extreme-right.png"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div  class="pager-control">
                        <div  id="pagerdevidercontainer">
                            <div  id="pagerdeviderdivfirst"></div>
                            <div  id="pagerdeviderdivsecond"></div>
                        </div>
                        <label >Page</label>
                        <input  accept="number" id="pagetextfield" type="text" ng-reflect-model="1" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
                        <label >of</label>
                        <label > </label>
                        <label >1</label>
                    </div>
                </div>`enter code here`
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/2971401/8932624

Comment: Where is your css?

Comment: You need to use `<tr></tr>` in `<tfoot>`

Comment: Refer this - https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/footer_callback.html

Comment: Explain for question briefly.

Comment: I have attached a sample image and i am using below css.container{
  height: 90%;
}

.tablelog{
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 660px;
  height: 90%;
  display:inline-block;
}

Answer (score 0):

See updated `<tfoot>` here -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table tablelog">
                <thead id="thead">
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <div style="width:15px;"></div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div id="div-style">Column 1</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div id="div-style">Column 2</div>
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div id="div-style">Column 3</div>
                        </th>
                        <th id="last-column">
                            <div>Column 4</div>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbody">
                    <tr class="active">
                        <td style="padding-right:15px;">
                            <div class="triangleright"></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="div-style">value</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="div-style">value</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="div-style">value</div>
                        </td>
                        <td id="last-column">value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-right:15px;">
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="div-style">value</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="div-style">value</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="div-style">value</div>
                        </td>
                        <td id="last-column">value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-right:15px;">
                            <div></div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="div-style">value</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="div-style">value</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div id="div-style">value</div>
                        </td>
                        <td id="last-column">value</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <!-- <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th colspan=3>
                            <button id="page-selector-button-control" type="button" disabled=""><img id="page-selector-button-control-image" src="images/extreme-left.png">1</button>
                            <button id="page-selector-button-control" type="button" disabled=""><img id="page-selector-button-control-image" src="images/arrow-left.png">2</button>
                            <button id="page-selector-button-control" type="button" disabled=""><img id="page-selector-button-control-image" src="images/arrow-right.png">3</button>
                            <button id="page-selector-button-control" type="button" disabled=""><img id="page-selector-button-control-image" src="images/extreme-right.png">4</button>
                        </th>
                        <th colspan=1>
                            <label>Page</label>
                            <input accept="number" id="pagetextfield" type="text" ng-reflect-model="1" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
                            <label>of</label>
                            <label> </label>
                            <label>1</label>
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot> -->
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<footer style="position: fixed;bottom: 0px;" class="col-xs-12">
    <div id="pageselectorButtonContainr" class="col-xs-6">
        <button id="page-selector-button-control" type="button" disabled=""><img id="page-selector-button-control-image" src="images/extreme-left.png"></button>
        <button id="page-selector-button-control" type="button" disabled=""><img id="page-selector-button-control-image" src="images/arrow-left.png"></button>
        <button id="page-selector-button-control" type="button" disabled=""><img id="page-selector-button-control-image" src="images/arrow-right.png"></button>
        <button id="page-selector-button-control" type="button" disabled=""><img id="page-selector-button-control-image" src="images/extreme-right.png"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="pager-control col-xs-6 pull-right">
        <label>Page</label>
        <input accept="number" id="pagetextfield" type="text" ng-reflect-model="1" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid">
        <label>of</label>
        <label> </label>
        <label>1</label>
    </div>
</footer>

</html>
```

I've also used bootstrap here, which is useful for responsive design.

Comment: Thanks Tushar. But i need to always stick the footer at bottom in spite of number of counts.Even if i try to add blank rows that will solve the responsiveness

Comment: Here, footer will always stick to table's bottom & you'll add new rows in `<tbody>` as required.

Comment: Is there any way i can stick the footer to bottom always like in the sample image i have attached

Comment: check an updated code, now using page `<footer>` instead of `<tfoot>`

Comment: @Tushar Walzade Maybe you can help me. Look at this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58312493/how-can-i-custom-table-responsive-materialize